# Pyautogui keeps clicking at the mouse location after finding the image

Tags: python, pyautogui

The code below keeps clicking on its own after finding the set image and clicking on it but after that it keeps clicking by itself on the current mouse x,y.

How can i make it so the click will only happen 1x after it finds image.

```
import queue
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(2)


while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    
    eventicon = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("SummerEventBot\eventicon.png")
    pyautogui.click(eventicon)
```

Comment: It's in a while block so it will keep clicking. Is the image moving or what?

Comment: Also, please remove unused imports from your code example.

Comment: The image is a "button" and once the button gets clicked that image is gone from the screen but it keeps clicking even tho the image is gone

Comment: What is the while block for then?

Comment: To stop the script by holding down Q key since i will be adding more steps/images to detect but i only want them to be clicked once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pyautogui doesn't find the desired image, it returns `None` instead of coordinates. When you pass `None` to `click()`, it just clicks on the current position. So you need to check if you actually found the image. You can do that by checking if the locate function didn't return `None`.

```py
while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    
    eventicon = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("SummerEventBot\eventicon.png")
    if eventicon is not None:
        pyautogui.click(eventicon)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a break statement? It seems he wants it to click one time after finding the image.

Comment: @Jobo I have no idea how OP wants to actually use the while block, it honestly confuses me. 
I think there is, when finished, meant to be a bigger script in the while block which will be meant to repeat when finished. I agree the while block is strange, but this is the answer to OP's question.